# Nested SELECT clause in SQL Compact 3.5

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-ce, subquery

In this post "[select with nested select](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlce/thread/ac926272-2382-4acb-84e3-fc32945c7cea)" I read that SQL Compact 3.5 (SP1) support nested SELECT clause. But my request not work:

*t1 - table 1
t2 - table 2
c1, c2 = columns*

```
select 
 t1.c1, 
 t1.c2, 
 (select count(t2.c1) from t2 where t2.id = t1.id) as count_t 
from 
 t1
```

Does SQL Compact 3.5 SP1 support nested SELECT clause in this case?

Update:

SQL Compact 3.5 SP1 work with this type of nested request:

- SELECT ... from ... where .. **IN (SELECT** ...)
- SELECT ... **from (SELECT** ...)

Comment: What error do you get on this query?

Comment: Error: "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 40,Token in error = select ]"

Comment: Ok, answered *revised* question too

Comment: Have we answered the new question yet?????

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank all for help and advise.

The final answer for question - **NO. SQL Compact 3.5 SP1 does not support nested select clause.**

Comment: Does someone know if in SQL Compact 4 Nested query works? I'm having a similar issue but I can't believe that it does not still work!!!

Comment: I answer to my comment myself... NO, IT DOES NOT WORK

Answer (score 6):

You're attempting to equate a scalar value with what is notionally a result set.

Try

```
select * from LogMagazines where id IN (select max(id) from UserRoles)
```

Ok, I answered the question and you asked a completely new and different question which is not quite how its supposed to work, but to answer the *new* question what you need to do is a join:

```
SELECT 
    t1.c1,  
    t1.c2,  
    count_t.c
FROM 
    t1 JOIN (select id, count(t2.c1) as c from t2 GROUP BY t2.id) count_t 
       ON t1.id = count_t.id
```

Or thereabouts

Answer (score 1):

Try running `select max(Id) from UserRoles`
And make sure this returns a proper result.
Then try `select * from LogMagazines where id =`
With that result, its possible you have an error somewhere.

Comment: BTW, id = (select ...)
Is invalid if the subselect returns multiple lines, then you'd want 
id IN (select ....) though I'm not sure if that is valid with Compact 3.5

Comment: Thank you. Select * ... IN () work with SQL Compact 3.5 (SP1). But in my case i need another nested request.I update my question to point new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need

`select * from LogMagazines where id = (select max id from UserRoles)`

?

Comment: Same problem: "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 40,Token in error = select ]"

Comment: Maybe the post you cited is wrong, and only 3.5SP1 supports the sub-select queries?