# Select last record and replace value if exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

Lets say I have a record of people and their relationship statuses. I also have a table where I have chosen to give these people my own names. Something like this:

```
Statuses                                  Names
ID | Name | Status   | Date               ID | Name
---------------------------------         -------------
01 | Lisa | Divorced | 2013-01-01         01 | Lizzza
02 | John | Married  | 2013-04-04         03 | Alex
01 | Lisa | Married  | 2013-05-05
01 | Lisa | Single   | 2014-01-23
02 | John | Single   | 2014-01-24
```

I would now like to select the last status for each person, in this list I would also like to see people from the list with names, even if they are not in the Status-table. In the scenario above, I would like like to have this result:

```
ID | Name   | Status | Date
---------------------------------
01 | Lizzza | Single | 2014-01-23
02 | John   | Single | 2014-01-24
03 | Alex   | NULL   | NULL
```

I made a similar question yesterday at this thread; [Select from other table if value exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305474/select-from-other-table-if-value-exist) but this query will get me the whole list of statuses. This time I just want the last known record and not all of them.

Quick edit, I'm using SQL Compact / SQL CE

Comment: Does Sql CE support Ranking functions ?

Comment: You can achieve it using Rank() function (if SQL CE support) and group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT * 
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS rn
FROM TableName
)Q
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: This fails. It seems like it's the rn = ROW_NUMBER.. that fails. It says there's an error on this row, "Token in error = = "

Comment: try now it works fine with Sql Server but not sure about SQL CE.

Comment: Well, i feel stupid that I did not alter that line myself, but I how ever got error on "OVER" now.

Answer (score 0):

```
select n.id,n.name,s.status,s.date from name n
left outer join statuses s on n.id=s.id and 
s.date =(select max(date) from statuses st where st.id=n.id )
```

Comment: It feels like this is something i can use, but i get error on the select. I get "Token in Error = SELECT". Which is strange. The "LEFT OUTER JOIN" is not supported, but selecting WERE MAX ... should be doable.

Comment: BTW, should this not leave out Lisa? SELECT MAX(Date)... should give me the last date...?

Comment: I tried in mssql,mysql.above code works perfectly.Instead of left outer join just use left join

Comment: I like where you're going with this, but it's not enough - `John` isn't in `Names`.  Furthermore, there's no difference between `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (the `OUTER` is implicit).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse i thought names id is the foreign key of statuses id.so if record delete from base,dont want to show his/her status.

Comment: I tried to add '(SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Statuses) As Higest' just to test, but i get error on "SELECT". Due to this thread, i cant nest selection. I can how ever use 'WHERE NOT IN (SELECT ...)'. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941619/nested-select-clause-in-sql-compact-3-5

Comment: @gubbfett is it support top

Comment: @P.Sethuraman Well, if you mean the MAX() function, this is supported. It seems like I how ever can not nest a selection to use 'AS Something'. Understand what I mean?

Comment: @gubbfett what my question was is it support "top" expression. if its instead of inner select query use the below one                   select top(1)date from statuses st where st.id=n.id order by date desc

Comment: @P.Sethuraman it seems like it due to this article, but i get error when i try to use it http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb686896.aspx

Comment: @gubbfett select n.id,n.name,s.status,s.date from name n
    left outer join statuses s on n.id=s.id and 
    s.date =(select top(1)date
from statuses st where st.id=n.id order by date desc)

Comment: @gubbfett shall i know what version you can  use now

Comment: @P.Sethuraman I get error on 'SELECT' when trying to match a value to a query. The version is 3.5.8080.0

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH e AS
(
     SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER
         (
             PARTITION BY ID
             ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, [Date], 101) DESC
         ) AS Recency
     FROM [Statuses]
)
SELECT e.*, n.name
FROM e left outer join names n  on e.id=n.id 
WHERE Recency = 1
```

Comment: I get "Token in error = OVER". This function does not seem to work at all in CE.